# How to get a file from laravel folder storage for a treatment

Tags: laravel, get, filesystems, storage

I saved an image in storage / app / public and I created a symbolic link to public / storage and the link works well but when I try to get the image with the method `Storage :: get ($path)` I am being sent a `FileNotFoundException`. I would like to know how to get my image in my code

```
 $fichier=Storage::get('storage/avatarDebutFemme.png');
```

> Illuminate \ Contracts \ Filesystem \ FileNotFoundException
>   storage/avatarDebutFemme.png

Previous exceptions

> File not found at path: storage/avatarDebutFemme.png (0)

Answer (score 0):

To access your storage path you should use the [storage helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-storage-path) for getting the path:

```php
$fichier = Storage::get(storage_path('app/public/avatarDebutFemme.png'));
```

Would get a file called `avatarDebutFemme.png` located in the folder `storage/app/public` of your Laravel project.

Comment: $fichier = Storage::get(storage_path('app\avatarDebutFemme.png'));

Comment: I did as you said but without any success

Comment: What error are you getting? The bar should be `/` not `\\`

Comment: Illuminate \ Contracts \ Filesystem \ FileNotFoundException
C:\wamp64\www\projetFE\storage\app/public/avatarDebutFemme.png   that's the error message

Comment: I didnt know you were on windows, use '/' instead then.

Answer (score 0):

Follow ,laravel site it can be helpfull for your problem [File Storage-Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem)

Comment: I did as they said on this site but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

tested and works
storage_path() use absolute path 
you will need To create the symbolic link

```
php artisan storage:link
```

view img tag

```
src="{{route('employee.get.image', $employee->id)}}"
```

below is function

```
$path = storage_path('app/public/'.$image_url);//this will load storage/app/public/
    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        $path = public_path('images/avatar.jpg');
    }
    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type",'image/jpeg');

    return $response;
```